# unknown harddisk partitions and unallocated space to be merged in an existing partition

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

Pardon me for the long title, but I have a few problems at hand and hence the title.

See below screenshot from the disk management console in my system.

[image: Partitions on my System]

The partitions marked with red blocks are not known to me and they occupy about 18 gigs of space on my system. I can read that they are recovery, EFI and OEM partitions. But I didn't created them in the first place.

I have gone through [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdHjolzl7Gk) on how to create, shrink and extend partitions in Windows 10. I have been able to get approx 215 gigs from my C: as unallocated space. However, I am not able to extend my G: to claim this space.

I am not able to click the "extend" menu on G:, as it is disabled.

I have gone through a few other articles but of no use.

1. I want this unallocated space to be extended to G:
2. If I may, I would want to have the other unknown partitions also to be merged in G:

My system is Windows 10 and my disk drive capacity is 1TB. I can provide other details if prompted as I don't know which information can be useful.

Comment: If you have any unallocated space after the drive (G In your case) which you want to extand, then only you can extend.

Comment: Poor hard drive...my recommendation is to fully delete everything and create only the needed partitions. The drive has become a mess. Reallocation from what's in there could cause quite some anomalies given how many 'recovery' ones are.